# Chamfer distance Raises Error in a Keras autoencoder model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, point-clouds

I am currently designing an auto-encoder using PointNet algorithm, I am facing a problem, apparently in my loss function Chamfer-distance.
I try to run the training process but the following Error raises.

I would really appreciate your help.

```
ValueError: Expected list with element dtype float but got list with element dtype double for '{{node gradient_tape/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/gradients/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/TensorArrayV2Write/TensorListSetItem_grad/TensorListGetItem}} = TensorListGetItem[element_dtype=DT_FLOAT](gradient_tape/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/gradients/grad_ys_0, gradient_tape/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/gradients/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/TensorArrayV2Write/TensorListSetItem_grad/TensorListSetItem/TensorListPopBack:1, gradient_tape/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/gradients/chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/TensorArrayV2Write/TensorListSetItem_grad/Shape)' with input shapes: [], [], [0].


ERROR:tensorflow:Error: Input value Tensor("chamfer_distance_tf/map/while/add:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) has dtype <dtype: 'float32'>, but expected dtype <dtype: 'float64'>.  This leads to undefined behavior and will be an error in future versions of TensorFlow.
```

Here is my loss function:

```
def distance_matrix(array1, array2):

    num_point, num_features = array1.shape
    expanded_array1 = tf.tile(array1, (num_point, 1))
    expanded_array2 = tf.reshape(
            tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(array2, 1), 
                    (1, num_point, 1)),
            (-1, num_features))
    distances = tf.norm(expanded_array1-expanded_array2, axis=1)
    distances = tf.reshape(distances, (num_point, num_point))
    return distances

def av_dist(array1, array2):
 
    distances = distance_matrix(array1, array2)
    distances = tf.reduce_min(distances, axis=1)
    distances = tf.reduce_mean(distances)
    return distances

def av_dist_sum(arrays):
    
    array1, array2 = arrays
    av_dist1 = av_dist(array1, array2)
    av_dist2 = av_dist(array2, array1)
    return av_dist1+av_dist2

def chamfer_distance_tf(array1, array2):
    batch_size, num_point, num_features = array1.shape
    dist = tf.reduce_mean(
               tf.map_fn(av_dist_sum, elems=(array1, array2), dtype=tf.float64), axis=-1)
    return dist

print(chamfer_distance_tf(X,X))


model.compile(
    loss= chamfer_distance_tf,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],)

model.fit(train_data, train_data, epochs=5, batch_size=10)`
```

and Here is the first part of the code:

```
list_pcl = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".ply") :
        directory_file = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        print(directory_file)
        pcl = PlyData.read(directory_file)
        data = pcl.elements[0].data
        data = np.asarray(data.tolist())
        data.resize(1024,3)
        print(type(data))
        print(data.shape)
        list_pcl.append(data)
print(len(list_pcl))


#X = np.asarray(list_pcl[0:73999])
#X_val = np.asarray(list_pcl[74000:74299])
#X_test = np.asarray(list_pcl[74300:74329])

X = np.asarray(list_pcl[0:200])
X_val = np.asarray(list_pcl[200:220])
X_test = np.asarray(list_pcl[220:228])

random.shuffle(X)
random.shuffle(X_val)
random.shuffle(X_test)

"""**Reshaping the dataset**

The neural network is unable to treat data with different input size, that's why we apply a zero padding to all the data to reach the size of the point cloud data with the biggest number of raws. 
We additioally reshape the outcome by adding one dimension corresponidng to the number of channels to the tesors.
"""

train_num = X.shape[0]
val_num = X_val.shape[0]
test_num = X_test.shape[0]
points_num = X.shape[1]
features_num = X.shape[2]

train_data = X.reshape([-1, points_num, features_num]).astype(float)
val_data = X_val.reshape([-1, points_num, features_num]).astype(float)
test_data = X_test.reshape([-1, points_num, features_num]).astype(float)

print(train_data.shape)
print(val_data.shape)
print(test_data.shape)
```

Comment: did u try to change dtype=tf.float64 into dtype=tf.float32 in tf.map_fn ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, Yes and I get this Error:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray dtype is float32 but Op is trying to write dtype float64